# Create collection of type

Tags: f#

I created a record type

```
type IpRanges = {ipStart: IPAddress; ipEnd: IPAddress; subnet: IPAddress; mask: IPAddress}
```

How can I create a collection type of IpRanges?

```
type CollRanges = ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of collection do you want to create?

A list of IPRanges? If so you can do it like this:

```
type CollRanges = List<IpRanges>
```

But since list is generic your `CollRanges` doesn't really need to be a new type, indeed the previous line will create a type alias which is a good thing since you will reuse all the functionality of the List type and your collection will be more cohesive (*plugabble*) with existing F# code. The same applies to any other generic collection, like Array, Seq, ResizeArray, ...

Comment: Well in fact it would be `let (list:List<IpRanges>) = `  or you can do directly `let list = [range1;range2; ...]` and it will be inferred. In case you want to add a type annotation you can use that notation or simply `let (list :IpRanges list) = ...`

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new in f#. So `let (list :IpRanges list)` or `let variable (list :IpRanges list)`. How the compiler knows, when I type list instead List<type>, that is a list type.

Comment: Well `list`is an alias of `List` . They all mean the same thing unless you have opened the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` which has another `List` definition which is mutable. Finally in F# there is an alternative notation for generic types, so in addition to the standard .NET style `Type1<Type2>` you have the OCaml style `Type2 Type1`.